# Netlogo: Setting pcolor patches with specific distance from each other

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to set pcolor orange for different patches. I want them to be created randomly, but always at a distance of R from each other. In this current code, it creates the patches randomly just fine, but simply removes the orange patch if they are within the radius, resulting in fewer than N orange patches. How can I solve this so that all N patches are created at a distance R instead of just the ones which randomly fall out of radius R of each other?

```
      ask n-of N patches
      [ 
        if not any? other patches with [pcolor = orange] in-radius R [
    set pcolor orange
    ]]
```

Comment: what do you want it to do if there aren't any available patches? but it is likely that you can do what you want using `while`

Comment: It should always create a distribution where the patches are at a minimum distance of each other. If it can't do that it should do the same but with one fewer patch

Answer (score 0):

You are vey close, but asking `N` random patches can result in any number of orange patches, maybe one patch will get colored and the other random `N-1` patches will be within the radius `R`, even if there are lots of patches that still can be colored.
Maybe if you ask all patches you will obtain more consistent results,

```
ask patches
[
  if not any? other patches with [pcolor = orange] in-radius R 
     and count patches with [pcolor = orange] < N
  [
    set pcolor orange
  ]
]
```

In case that you want all the possible patches colored instead of just `N` you can remove (or comment) the whole line `and count patches with [pcolor = orange] < N`.

Also note that `ask patches` will iterate over the patches randomly, so if you need a reproducible or ordered coloring of the patches this is not the ideal way to do it.